# Delphi - package, XML parsing and DTD

Tags: xml, delphi, dom, package, dtd

I'm working with RAD Studio XE7. In a Delphi package I'm creating, I need to parse an XML containing the following SVG data:

```xml
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="141.73px" height="141.73px" viewBox="0 0 141.73 141.73" enable-background="new 0 0 141.73 141.73" xml:space="preserve">
    <linearGradient id="SVGID_1_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="67.6445" y1="90.6875" x2="99.4551" y2="90.6875">
        <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#26B5E3"/>
        <stop  offset="0.4887" style="stop-color:#3FBEED;stop-opacity:0.5113"/>
        <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#47C1F1;stop-opacity:0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <path fill="url(#SVGID_1_)" d="M94.25,82.792l5.205-4.868c-3.235,14.581-16.266,25.527-31.811,25.527v-9.033c10.257,0,19.001-6.592,22.22-15.765L94.25,82.792z"/>
    <path fill="#26B5E3" d="M99.479,63.931C96.303,49.282,83.23,38.279,67.645,38.279c-17.966,0-32.589,14.616-32.589,32.582c0,17.967,14.624,32.59,32.589,32.59v-9.033c-12.99,0-23.557-10.566-23.557-23.557c0-12.982,10.567-23.55,23.557-23.55c10.567,0,19.534,7.004,22.507,16.604l-15.937-0.042l10.017,9.46l5.633,5.32l4.386,4.139l5.205-4.868l4.854-4.549l10.065-9.411L99.479,63.931z"/>
</svg>
```

In my package, I use the following code to read the XML document:

```pascal
uses ..., Xml.XMLIntf, Xml.XMLDoc, Xml.Win.msxmldom, ...

var
    pDocument: IXMLDocument;
    ...
begin
    ...
    // load file
    pDocument := LoadXMLDocument(fileName);
    ...
end;
```

This code works well while the XML does not contain the following line:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

However with this line in the XML I get an error: "DTD is prohibited"

I know that this error is well known, and adding the following line should resolve the issue:

```pascal
Xml.Win.msxmldom.MSXMLDOMDocumentFactory.AddDOMProperty('ProhibitDTD', False);
```

And it's the case: The error is no more generated while the XML is loaded. However all the content of my document seems to become corrupted: some nodes loose their names, all the attribute contents are always empty, ... This strange behavior never happen if I comment the AddDOMProperty('ProhibitDTD', False) in my package code and if I remove manually the line containing the DTD in my source XML. Also, the same code compiled inside an exe instead of a package works well, even when using the AddDOMProperty('ProhibitDTD', False) code.

So my questions are:

1. What I'm doing wrong? Why my XML document is completely broken when I activate the AddDOMProperty('ProhibitDTD', False) inside my package code?
2. What is the correct way to resolve the "DTD is prohibited" issue for a code executed inside a package? (please with example)

Regards

Comment: Preprocess the XML and remove the doctype and add a valid xml prolog?

Comment: whorsdaddy, thanks for your answer. I already considered this option, but it will be the least I will apply, first because the issue I face may be the signal of a more deep problem, second because I consider that ignore a problem it is the better way to encounter many other on my road. For that I prefer understand what happen here before applying a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the source of the problem. In fact, I was committing a gross error. After loading the XML, I tried to get the first node this way:

```pascal
pNode := pDocument.ChildNodes['svg'];
```

Instead, getting it this way:

```pascal
pNode := pDocument.DocumentElement;
```

I noticed that the issue gone away and all my nodes data were in their correct location.

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry. I wrongly supposed that the issue was located in the load process itself, not in the parsing after.